# How can I parse a filename using a regular expressions in Python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I've got the following filename: `aabbcc_id_1112233.png` which translates to the following regexp: `[A-Za-z0-9]_id_[0-9].png` where `[x]` means it may contain `>= 1` symbols of `x`. How can I put it into python regexp library to return tuple: `(id, id_name)`?

E.g., for `aabbcc22_id_123.png` I want to receive `(id, id_name) = ('aabbcc22', 'id_123')`.

The usecase: currently I do `.split()` by an underscore which is hacky since I have to use indexes:

```
    base = filename.split('.')[0]
    return (base.split('_')[0], '_'.join(base.split('_')[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
>>> import re
>>> get_id = re.compile('(.*)_(id_.*)[.]png')
>>> get_id.findall('aabbcc22_id_123.png')
[('aabbcc22', 'id_123')]
>>>
```

And you can assign the values to `id` and `id_name` variables using this:

```
>>> [(id, id_name)] = get_id.findall('aabbcc22_id_123.png')
>>> id, id_name
('aabbcc22', 'id_123')
>>>
```